# ImageView - implementing gestures (pinch zoom, double tap) compatible with ViewPager (just like Android Gallery)

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager, android-image, android-gesture

I was looking for an effective way to implement gestures for `ImageView` with `ViewPager`.
I tried some examples, but they are not working well (e.g. pinch zoom actually is not zooming where I want it to).
In my app I need pinch zooming, double tap zoom and dragging the zoomed image.

What is the fastest and easiest way to make it all work well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this open source project: https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview