# Android: view single picture like photo gallery

Tags: android, android-layout

it seem like split actionbar for me, when i onClick or onTouch the screen the top and bottom menu will hide it with slide effect. This behavior also similar to facebook app and whatapp when view single image.

how can i do it? please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to use GestureListerner in android. For scroll up and down.

please use below link and modify code according to your need.

1. https://github.com/falnatsheh/EcoGallery
2. https://github.com/diegocarloslima/ByakuGallery
3. [View Pager + ImageView +Pinch Zoom + Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943831/view-pager-imageview-pinch-zoom-rotation)
4. [ImageView - implementing gestures (pinch zoom, double tap) compatible with ViewPager (just like Android Gallery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517306/imageview-implementing-gestures-pinch-zoom-double-tap-compatible-with-viewp)

Answer (score 0):

try this, may be it help you.

```
  public void onClick(View v) {

        if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH ){
            imgDisplay.setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION );

        }
        else if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB )
            imgDisplay.setSystemUiVisibility( View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN );
        else{}

}
```